# Providing data to sklearn.svm.SVC()

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to give those training data to `sklearn.svm.SVC()` but it returns the error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` when I try to `clf.fit(v,v2)`. How do we process this data before giving it to `SVC()`?

```
from PIL import Image
from sklearn import svm
for i in xrange(1,55):
    t = list(Image.open("train/"+str(i)+".png").getdata())
    v.append(t)
v = np.asarray(v)
v2 = np.array(["1","F","9","D","E","E","E","9","0","D","0","3","C","B","F","9","A","E","B","8","A","8","7",
               "9","9","3","C","6","1","E","6","6","C","C","F","A","8","0","1","F","F","E","9","4","6","0",
               "7","2","D","9","A","C","7","E"])
clf = svm.SVC()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
from scipy import misc
import glob
from sklearn import svm

filenames = glob.glob('train/*.png')
X = [misc.imread(each).flatten() for each in filenames]
y = ["1","F","9","D","E","E", ...]
model = svm.SVC().fit(X, y)
```

Notes:

- `X` has the form `(n_images, n_pixels)` where `n_pixels=width*height`
- `y` has length `n_images` (54 in your example)

This is just a start, you should try to feed the classifier with more meaningful features that single pixels.

Comment: `SVC(X,y)` gives a SVC with C value = X and kernel = y. `model.fit(X,y)` gives out the same error.

Comment: yes thanks for pointing that out, fixed. If it is not running then it is probably a problem with your data (ex: are all png the same dimensions?), the code runs ok on my end.

Comment: I added `for i in filenames:
    im31 = Image.open(i).resize(19,19).save(i)`. Now it fits. It cannot predict accurately, but I'll try to solve this. Thanks for your help